# Magento 2 How to return JSON object in rest response

Tags: magento2, rest-api, json, magento2.4.4

I want to return the JSON response suggested by the mobile app developer. My custom rest API currently returning responses in the below format.

```
[{
"status": true,
"data": [
  {
    "entity_id": "3",
    "name": "Test category",
    "icon_name": "test",
    "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/catalog/category/view/s/test-category/id/3/",
    "button_name": "Sell Now"
  },
  {
    "entity_id": "4",
    "name": "magento Test",
    "icon_name": null,
    "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/catalog/category/view/s/magento-test/id/4/",
    "button_name": "Sell Now"
  }
]}]
```

And below is the expected result:

```
 {"status": true,
    "data": [
      {
        "entity_id": "3",
        "name": "Test category",
        "icon_name": "test",
        "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/catalog/category/view/s/test-category/id/3/",
        "button_name": "Sell Now"
      },
      {
        "entity_id": "4",
        "name": "magento Test",
        "icon_name": null,
        "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/catalog/category/view/s/magento-test/id/4/",
        "button_name": "Sell Now"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The code that I have implemented:
Interface:

```
 /**
     * Get category collection
     *
     * @api
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryCollection();
```

Model:

```
public function getCategoryCollection()
      {
          try
          {
            $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');         
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();          
            $i=0;
            if(count($collection)){
              foreach ($collection as $category){
                $data[$i]=["entity_id" => $category->getId(),
                            "name"=> $category->getName(),
                            "icon_name" => $category->getData('category_icon_name'),
                            "category_url" => $category->getUrl(),
                            "button_name" => "Sell Now"
                            ];
                      $i++;
                }
                $output = ["status"=>true, "data"=>$data];
            }
            else{
              $output=["status"=>false,"message"=>"No Category found"];
            }            
            return [$output]; 
          }
          catch (\Exception $exception) { 
            $output=["status"=> false, 'message' => $exception->getMessage()];
            return [$output];
          }
      }
```

I got one solution to add the below code but using that might be not appropriate:

```
print_r(json_encode($output)); 
die();
```

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: return $output; instead of return [$output]; should do the trick.

Comment: also please not that this is not how responses normally look like in m2

Comment: when using only return $output; getting response like:  
[
  true,
  [
    {
      "entity_id": "3",
      "name": "Test category",
      "icon_name": "test",
      "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/catalog/category/view/s/test-category/id/3/",
      "button_name": "Sell Now"
    },
    {
      "entity_id": "4",
      "name": "magento Test",
      "icon_name": null,
      "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/catalog/category/view/s/magento-test/id/4/",
      "button_name": "Sell Now"
    }
  ]
]

Comment: then you have to create a response model that represents your format. as i said: you're showing the response in a format that is unusual in magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending response like this

$this->response is object of  **\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response** class

```
  $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true)
                ->setBody(json_encode($output))
                ->sendResponse();
```

Comment: response is which class's object?

Comment: this should not be used in webapi controllers

Comment: Getting response like this:     can't parse JSON.  Raw result:

{"status":true,"data":[{"entity_id":"3","name":"Test category","icon_name":"test","category_url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/magento\/pub\/catalog\/category\/view\/s\/test-category\/id\/3\/","button_name":"Sell Now"},{"entity_id":"4","name":"magento Test","icon_name":null,"category_url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/magento\/pub\/catalog\/category\/view\/s\/magento-test\/id\/4\/","button_name":"Sell Now"}]}[]

Comment: Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response Inject this response object in your class using dependency injection

Comment: We should use 

        $jsonResponse = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);

 from the controller

Comment: No, its not just a normal controller, using the result factory is of no use.